# Using an Alias column in the where clause in ms-sql 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know you cannot use a alias column in the where clause for T-SQL; however, has Microsoft provided some kind of workaround for this?

> **Related Questions:**
>
> - [Unknown Column In Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200200/can-you-use-an-alias-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql)
> - [Can you use an alias in the WHERE clause in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153598/unknown-column-in-where-clause)
> - [“Invalid column name” error on SQL statement from OpenQuery results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46354/invalid-column-name-error-on-sql-statement-from-openquery-results)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

One workaround would be to use a derived table.

For example:

```
select *
from 
   (
   select a + b as aliased_column
   from table
   ) dt
where dt.aliased_column = something.
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have always just repeated the SQL, this is soooo much better!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are aliasing, you could turn it into a user defined function and reference that in both places. Otherwise your copying the aliased code in several places, which tends to become very ugly and means updating 3+ spots if you are also ordering on that column.