# Get the nearest longitude and latitude from MSSQL database table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Ok I have searched SO and Google but haven't really found a definitive answer so throwing it out there for the SO community.

Basically I have a table of longitudes and latitudes for specific points of interest, the sql query will know which location you are currently at (which would be one of those in the table, passed in as a parameter), therefore it then needs to calculate and return the one row that is the nearest latitude and longitude to the passed in one.

I require this to all be done in MSSQL (2012 / stored proc) rather than in the calling application (which is .NET) as I have heard that SQL is usually much quicker at processing such queries than .NET would be?

EDIT:

I have found the STDistance Function which gives the number of miles between locations such as :

```
DECLARE @NWI geography, @EDI geography
SET @NWI = geography::Point(52.675833,1.282778,4326)
SET @EDI = geography::Point(55.95,-3.3725,4326)
SELECT @NWI.STDistance(@EDI) / 1000
```

However I don't want to have to iterate through all of the lat/lons in the table as surely this would be terrible for performance?

I also tried converting one of the examples pointed out in one of the below comment links (which was MYSQL not MSSQL) however I am getting an error, the code is as follows:

```
DECLARE @orig_lat decimal(6,2), @orig_long decimal(6,2), @bounding_distance int
set @orig_lat=52.056736; 
set @orig_long=1.14822; 
set @bounding_distance=1;

SELECT *,((ACOS(SIN(@orig_lat * PI() / 180) * SIN('lat' * PI() / 180) + COS(@orig_lat * PI() / 180) * COS('lat' * PI() / 180) * COS((@orig_long - 'lon') * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS 'distance' 
FROM [DB1].[dbo].[LatLons]
WHERE
(
  'lat' BETWEEN (@orig_lat - @bounding_distance) AND (@orig_lat + @bounding_distance)
  AND 'lon' BETWEEN (@orig_long - @bounding_distance) AND (@orig_long + @bounding_distance)
)
ORDER BY 'distance' ASC
```

The error received is:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 6 Error converting data type varchar
>   to numeric.

Anyone able to work out the above code or come up with a better solution?

Comment: This might be what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592209/find-closest-numeric-value-in-database

Comment: Looks like your answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826430/great-circle-distance-formula-t-sql

Comment: If suggested topics doesn't help you, please post your sample data.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your suggestions however neither link seems to definitively give the answer I am looking for, I've expanded my question a little if it helps at all?

Comment: In your example, is distance is in miles or kilometers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a blog a couple years ago that explains how this can be done without using the spatial data types.  Since it appears as though you have a table of longitude/latitude values, this blog will likely help a lot.

[SQL Server Zipcode Latitude Longitude Proximity Search](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-zipcode-latitude-longitude-pr)

[Same page saved from Archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20180711144737/http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-zipcode-latitude-longitude-pr)

Comment: @G Mastros Your blog post is just Genius! With a very minor tweak I was able to get it working against my data and I must admit it's performance is legendary my sincere thanks for helping to resolve my question :-)

Answer (score 11):

Let's look at a simple example of using the `STDistance` function in SQL Server 2008 (and later).

I'm going to tell SQL Server that I'm in London, and I want to see how far away each of my offices are.  Here's the results that I want SQL Server to give me:

[image: Offices]

First, we'll need some sample data.  We'll create a table containing a few locations of Microsoft offices, and we'll store their longitude & latitude values in a `geography` field.

```
CREATE TABLE [Offices] (
    [Office_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Office_Name] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [Office_Location] [geography] NOT NULL,
    [Update_By] nvarchar(30) NULL,
    [Update_Time] [datetime]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Offices] VALUES ('Microsoft Zurich', 'POINT(8.590847 47.408860 )', 'mike', GetDate())
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Offices] VALUES ('Microsoft San Francisco', 'POINT(-122.403697 37.792062 )', 'mike', GetDate())
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Offices] VALUES ('Microsoft Paris', 'POINT(2.265509 48.833946)', 'mike', GetDate())
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Offices] VALUES ('Microsoft Sydney', 'POINT(151.138378 -33.796572)', 'mike', GetDate())
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Offices] VALUES ('Microsoft Dubai', 'POINT(55.286282 25.228850)', 'mike', GetDate())
```

Now, supposing we were in London.  Here's how to make a `geography` value out of London's longitude & latitude values:

```
DECLARE 
    @latitude numeric(12, 7),
    @longitude numeric(12, 7)

SET @latitude = 51.507351
SET @longitude = -0.127758

DECLARE @g geography = 'POINT(' + cast(@longitude as nvarchar) + ' ' + cast(@latitude as nvarchar) + ')';
```

And finally, lets see how far each of our offices is.

```
SELECT [Office_Name], 
       cast([Office_Location].STDistance(@g) / 1609.344 as numeric(10, 1)) as 'Distance (in miles)' 
FROM [Offices]
ORDER BY 2 ASC
```

And this gives us the results we were hoping for.

[image: Results]

Obviously, you could slip in a `TOP(1)` if you just wanted to see the *closest* office.

[image: Top1results]

Cool, hey ?

There's just one snag.  When you have a lot of `geography` points to compare against, performance isn't brilliant, even if you add a SPATIAL INDEX on that database field.

I tested a point against a table of 330,000 `geography` points.  Using the code shown here, it found the closest point in about **8 seconds**.

When I modified my table to store the longitude and latitude values, and used the `[dbo].[fnCalcDistanceMiles]` function [from this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22476600/391605), it found the closest point in about **3 seconds**.

However...

All of the "distance between two points" samples I found on the internet either used the SQL Server `STDistance` function, or mathematical formulae involving the (CPU-intensive) cos, sin and tan functions.

A faster solution was to travel back in time to high school, and remember how Pythagoras calculated the distance between two points.

Supposing we wanted to know the distance between London and Paris.

[image]

And here's my SQL Server function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[uf_CalculateDistance] (@Lat1 decimal(8,4), @Long1 decimal(8,4), @Lat2 decimal(8,4), @Long2 decimal(8,4))
RETURNS decimal (8,4) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @d decimal(28,10)

    SET @d = sqrt(square(@Lat1-@Lat2) + square(@Long1-@Long2))

    RETURN @d
END
```

Now, remember this function doesn't return a value in miles, kilometers, etc... it's merely comparing the longitude & latitude values.  And Pythagoras is meant to be used in 2D, and not comparing points on a round planet !

However, in my tests, it found the closest point within **1 second**, and produced the same results as using SQL Server's `STDistance` function.

So, feel free to use this function for comparing *relative distances*, but don't use this function if you need the actual distance itself.

Hope all this helps.

Comment: In your "Pythagoras" function, using `abs` is redundant ... e.g. `square(-3)` produces 9

Comment: If you only want to find the nearest, you don't even need the sqrt

Comment: is that in meter? or kilometer?

Answer (score 2):

In my table I have 5 fields:  [Name] ,[Timings] ,[Description], [Lattitude], [Longitude]. Here user can pass current location and distance within which he/she wants results.

```
declare @latitude float, @longitude float, @distance float 
select @latitude = 28.6493, @longitude = 77.2217 , @distance = 5
;with RestroomLocationsWithDistance as
    (
        select
        [Name]   ,[Timings]     ,[Description],   
        ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(@latitude) ) * cos( radians( [Lattitude] ) ) * cos( radians( [Longitude] )
       - radians(@longitude) ) + sin( radians(@latitude) ) * sin( radians( [Lattitude] ) ) ) )  As Distance            
        FROM [dbo].[Locations]
    )
    select
    [Name]   ,[Timings]     ,[Description],    Distance        
    from RestroomLocationsWithDistance
    where Distance <= @distance
```

Comment: is distance in miles or kilometers?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is SQL Server, just put a Spatial Index on the Lat/Lon column of your table and then query it it using the `.STDistance()` function in your WHERE clause.

This article from the Microsoft doc explains how to do it.:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929109.aspx.  The second section "**Nearest Neighbor Query..**" seems particularly relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Here how I used Mike's function above:

```
    SELECT TOP 1 [State], [City], [AddressID], sqrt(square(abs(la.Latitude-@lat)) + square(abs(la.Longitude-@lng))) as Distance
    FROM [LocationAddresses] la     
    ORDER BY Distance
```