# Nearest location data with spatial data laravel mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, spatial

I have read all related [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010916/how-to-show-stores-with-nearest-long-lat-values-using-search-function-laravel) to this issue but could not found solution.

I have saved coordinates in mysql colum type **point**, in laravel model i have saved like this

```
use Spatial;
protected $spatial = ['location'];
```

To get coordinates, i can do like this

```
$model->getCoordinates();
```

But i want to select all those records with is 10km distance, how  i can create laravel eloquent query for that?

Note: there is no lat,lon columns separately in my table so this query wont work

```
$results = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(' . $lat . ') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(' . $lng . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $lat .') ) * sin( radians(lat) ) ) ) AS distance FROM articles HAVING distance < ' . $distance . ' ORDER BY distance') );
```

Updated: I have used laravel Voyager to save map locations, here is [link](https://docs.laravelvoyager.com/customization/coordinates)

Comment: can you provide what $model->getCoordinates(); function actually does. and how the actual location is stored.

Comment: $model->getCoordinates(); This will return an array of coordinates with lat as the latitude and lng as the longitude. please see the voyager link for more details

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
$lon = 96.14344130;$lat = 16.86677920;$distance=10;

    MyNode::whereRaw(DB::raw( "(3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) 
                     * cos( radians( ST_Y(geom) ) )  
                     * cos( radians( ST_X(geom) ) - radians($lon) ) 
                     + sin( radians($lat) ) 
                     * sin( radians( ST_Y(geom) ) ) ) ) < $distance "))
                     ->take(10)->get();
```

Comment: I do not have lat,lng in my database table. there is only one field which save spatial data

Comment: Oh Sorry! Misunderstanding :-D .But Can't you  convert geom to lat,lng from your spatial database?

Comment: Voyger function [REF](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/blob/bb25c3f7369eb324e0a1b012458326e8c08fc942/src/Traits/Spatial.php) same function need to implimented in mySql.

Comment: I would like to know geom column type.Line String Or Point?

Comment: If your geom column is point you can query like DB::raw('ST_X(geom) as lng, ST_Y(geom) as lat')] or If your geom column is LineString Or Multilinestring you can query like this DB::raw('ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) as coordinates')] you will get Json Object with lat,lng.

Comment: @Amy: As i mentioned already, geom column is POINT., how i can select as per distance?

Comment: @ThataL: i can getCoordinates from that for single result. i want to select result with in distance. how to calculate distance on that?

Answer (score 0):

[$model->getCoordinates()](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/blob/bb25c3f7369eb324e0a1b012458326e8c08fc942/src/Traits/Spatial.php#L25-L50) returns array of coordinates. You can dump that and inspect array data. I think this exporting works.

```
list($lat, $lng) = $model->getCoordinates();
```

So you can have **$lat, $lng** variables.