# How to Display a List of Users based on current location in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hello I am working on a app in Xamarin forms  that allows users to get hired for gigs I have a parse service made that allows users to create accounts but I am having issues finding a way to display a list of current users that are in 25,50,and a 100 miles away from the person looking to book the users for this gigs.

are there any examples out there that can help me get started? I looked for a good 2 hours and couldn't find anything

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need is to get the user current location. For this, you can refer to [Geolocator](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin) plugin.

Then you will need to select out the users that is store with latitude and longitude information in your database table based on your defined distance.
You can refer to the samples [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17551156/get-the-nearest-longitude-and-latitude-from-mssql-database-table?rq=1) on how to do it.