# Why SQL case isn't working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, coldfusion, case, cfquery

I get an error;Invalid column name 'phase'. I've tried every permutation I can think of.

```
<cfargument name="locationFilter" default="" />
    <cfargument name="educationFilter" default="" />
    <cfargument name="workFilter" default="" />
    <cfargument name="diversityFilter" default="" />
    <cfargument name="phaseFilter" default="" />
    <cfquery name="QMentors" datasource="#request.dsn_live#">
        SELECT  
        (case 
        when datepart(year,getdate())-cast(yearstarted as integer) > 29 then '5'
        when datepart(year,getdate())-cast(yearstarted as integer) > 13 then '4'
        when datepart(year,getdate())-cast(yearstarted as integer) > 5 then '3'
        when datepart(year,getdate())-cast(yearstarted as integer) > 1 then '2'
        else '1'
        end) as phase, *
    FROM mentors 
    WHERE 0=0
    AND mentortype='mentor' 
    AND approved='true' 
    AND active='true' 
    AND mentorcat LIKE '%general%' 
        <cfif arguments.locationFilter neq ""> AND location LIKE <cfqueryparam value="%#arguments.locationFilter#%" /></cfif>
        <cfif arguments.educationFilter neq ""> AND educationhistory LIKE <cfqueryparam value="%#arguments.educationFilter#%" /></cfif>
        <cfif arguments.workFilter neq ""> AND workhistory LIKE <cfqueryparam value="%#arguments.workFilter#%" /></cfif>
        <cfif arguments.diversityFilter eq "Diversity"> AND mentorcat LIKE <cfqueryparam value="%#arguments.diversityFilter#%" /></cfif>
        <cfif arguments.phaseFilter neq ""> AND phase = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.phaseFilter#" /></cfif>
    ORDER BY lastname
</cfquery>
```

I thought I had better show the entire query.

Comment: which DBMS are you using? MySql/PostgreSQL/MS-SQL?

Comment: try to remove 'phase ='

Comment: Sorry it's MS SQL 2008

Comment: Your code is working just fine http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6fbcfc/1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT  
    (case 
    when datepart(year,getdate())-cast(yearstarted as integer) > 29 then '5'
    when datepart(year,getdate())-cast(yearstarted as integer) > 13 then '4'
    when datepart(year,getdate())-cast(yearstarted as integer) > 5 then '3'
    when datepart(year,getdate())-cast(yearstarted as integer) > 1 then '2'
    else '1'
    end) as phase, *
FROM table
```

EDIT:

You need repeat whole case in where

```
AND case 
    when datepart(year,getdate())-cast(yearstarted as integer) > 29 then '5'
    when datepart(year,getdate())-cast(yearstarted as integer) > 13 then '4'
    when datepart(year,getdate())-cast(yearstarted as integer) > 5 then '3'
    when datepart(year,getdate())-cast(yearstarted as integer) > 1 then '2'
    else '1'
    end) = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.phaseFilter#" /></cfif>
```

Or create `Select(your query) where phase = condition`

[Alias in where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260399/using-an-alias-column-in-the-where-clause-in-ms-sql-2000)

Comment: Still doesn't work for me.  I edited my post to put the entire query string up.

Comment: So I guess the answer is;  you can't use a variable created by a case statement in the where clause.

Comment: yes `AS` is only alias for column, not name, so you can't use alias in condition.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is wrong. This code should run:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT case
                when datepart(year,getdate())-cast(yearstarted as integer) > 29 then '5'
                when datepart(year,getdate())-cast(yearstarted as integer) > 13 then '4'
                when datepart(year,getdate())-cast(yearstarted as integer) > 5 then '3'
                when datepart(year,getdate())-cast(yearstarted as integer) > 1 then '2'
                else '1'
               end AS phase,
       col1, col2, col3, ... -- The list of columns that you want to select
  FROM table)
WHERE plase = ...
```

When you want to select a case expression, you can define the case expression and then give the column alias using the `AS` keyword as shown above.

If you want to update the column named `phase` in a table then your expression (as provided in the question) would be the right one.

**EDIT**

For the sake of maintainability, writing the entire `CASE` construct in the `WHERE` clause is quite tedious. Instead, use the main query inside an inline view (`SELECT` statement in the `FROM` clause) and filter on `phase = ...`.

Comment: Edited. Please check.

Comment: +1. Using a derived table is much more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
    case 
    when datepart(year,getdate())-cast(yearstarted as integer) > 29 then '5'
    when datepart(year,getdate())-cast(yearstarted as integer) > 13 then '4'
    when datepart(year,getdate())-cast(yearstarted as integer) > 5 then '3'
    when datepart(year,getdate())-cast(yearstarted as integer) > 1 then '2'
    else '1'
    end as phase, 
    *
FROM table
```