# Analytic function and where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have simple code like:

```
Select distinct a.Symbol,b.Symbol, corr(a.logp,b.logp) 
over (partition by a.symbol,b.symbol)  Correlation
    From logprofittest a, logprofittest b
    where a.Symbol<>b.symbol
    And  To_date(a.Tdate,'YYYYMMDD') between  DATE'2013-12-01' AND DATE'2013-12-31'
    and  To_date(b.Tdate,'YYYYMMDD') between  DATE'2013-12-01' AND DATE'2013-12-31'
    and  To_date(a.Tdate,'YYYYMMDD')=To_date(b.Tdate,'YYYYMMDD')
    and correlation>0.5
    Order by correlation desc;
```

However, error says `correlation>0.5` is wrong, how to fix it please?

Comment: Are you trying to use **field alias** in a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: See if [this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260399/using-an-alias-column-in-the-where-clause-in-ms-sql-2000)

Comment: Thanks for all your reply. I create a new a table to avoid this error