# T-SQL Column alias on computed column - Invalid column name

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm using an alias to refer to a computed column. Here is a snippet from the actual code I'm trying to make work, to compute similarity and return matches where the similarity score is 3 or higher.

```
select [FirstName], difference([FirstName], 'mitch') as similarity
from [Dev].[dbo].[Name]
where similarity > 2
order by similarity desc
```

Exception Message:

> Invalid column name 'similarity'.

As similarity is not a real column, how would I make this work?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Invalid column name" error on SQL statement from OpenQuery results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46354/invalid-column-name-error-on-sql-statement-from-openquery-results)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Column aliases and computations are performed in the projection (`SELECT`) phase of the query, which occurs after the selection (`WHERE` and `JOIN`) phase. Because of this, they can't be referenced in the `WHERE` clause or in a `JOIN` condition because they do not yet exist. You can either use your query with the `SELECT` clause as a subquery or you can duplicate the computation in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select * 

from
(select [FirstName], difference([FirstName], 'mitch') as similarity
from [Dev].[dbo].[Name]) src

where similarity > 2
order by similarity desc
```

or

```
select [FirstName], difference([FirstName], 'mitch') as similarity
from [Dev].[dbo].[Name]
where difference([FirstName], 'mitch') > 2
order by similarity desc
```

Answer (score 11):

All answers can solve your problem but for complicated situation you just can't duplicate your query.

The correct way is by using [CROSS and APPLY](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2010/01/25/referring-computedcalculated-columns-in-the-where-and-group-by-clause/)

```
select [FirstName], similarity
from [Dev].[dbo].[Name]
cross apply
  (
     select similarity =
     difference([FirstName], 'mitch')  
  )computed_column
where similarity > 2
order by similarity desc
```

whit CROSS and APPLY you can use your computed column everywhere on the query

Comment: I think this should be the answer. Note that you are required to give the cross apply a name. In this case, even though the "computed_column" alias is not used, you still have to define/include it. Keep it DRY!

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (
        SELECT [FirstName], difference([FirstName], 'mitch') as similarity
            FROM [Dev].[dbo].[Name]
        ) a
WHERE similarity > 2
ORDER BY similarity desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select [FirstName], difference([FirstName], 'mitch') as similarity
from [Dev].[dbo].[Name]
where difference([FirstName], 'mitch') > 2
order by 2 desc
```

You can't reference column aliases in where clause