# Call a user-defined function in SELECT, also use the value in WHERE, I don't want to call the function twice

Tags: t-sql, select, where-clause

Using TSQL, how can I get the value from a user-defined function by initially calling it in the SELECT clause but then also referencing the result in the WHERE clause?  I've tried creating an alias for the result but it cannot resolve the name

```
SELECT C.dbo.myFunction(n.first, n.last) AS result, <other columns>
FROM C.dbo.Names AS n, <other tables>
WHERE result > 10 AND <other conditions>
```

Am I going about this correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL Column alias on computed column - Invalid column name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591183/t-sql-column-alias-on-computed-column-invalid-column-name)

Comment: See Logical Processing Order of the SELECT Statement on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499(v=sql.110).aspx). `WHERE` happens *before* `SELECT`

Comment: Thank you, @Damien_The_Unbeliever, that's a great reminder as to _why_ this is not a valid approach on my part.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, thank you, that link helped in addition to your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use column aliases in `WHERE` clause. You can try following instead:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM 
    (SELECT C.dbo.myFunction(n.first, n.last) AS result, <other columns>
    FROM C.dbo.Names AS n, <other tables>) s
WHERE s.result > 10 AND <other conditions>
```

Answer (score 2):

AS mentioned by others, you can't use an alias in a `Where` clause. However, you could use a common table expression instead:

```
With CTE AS 
(SELECT C.dbo.myFunction(n.first, n.last) AS result, <other columns>
FROM C.dbo.Names AS n, <other tables> )

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE result > 10;
```