# How to add a where clause to a column from a correlated subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following correlated subquery in SQL Server which works fine

```
select *, [Status]=(select Max([Status]) from Data_121EmailLog o2 
where o2.Data_121Id = o1.Data_121Id) from Data_121 o1
```

You can see what's going on here from this screenshot

[image]

However, when I try to add a where clause on the column in the generated subquery it doesn't work

[image]

How can I added a where clause on the [Status] column. In my example this should return 1 result as there is only 1 record with a status of 2.

Comment: You can't use column alias in `where` clause: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6591216/1163867

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comment link by MarcinJuraszek solved it for me

```
SELECT * FROM (
select *, [Status]=(select Max([Status]) from Data_121EmailLog o2 
where o2.Data_121Id = o1.Data_121Id) from Data_121 o1) a where a.[Status] = 2
```