# re use existing selected column in sql server?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, code-reuse

Say I have a query that goes like this

```
select column1
,column2
,column3
,column4
,column5 + reusethiscolumn as Reusethiscolumn2
```

[*can i use here the data that will be derived from the column below?*]

```
,case[computation here] as reusethiscolumn
from table
```

is there any way to do this?
thanks in advance.

Comment: It is possible , to provide solution give some data and result

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591183/t-sql-column-alias-on-computed-column-invalid-column-name

Comment: No, you can't use a column alias at this point without using a subselect. You can use a column alias in the `ORDER BY` clause, see column_alias can be used in an ORDER BY clause. MySQL extends the use of column alias names to the `HAVING` and `GROUP BY` clauses

Comment: SQL processes all columns in the `SELECT` clause "as if" they're all being evaluated in parallel - this means that within a single `SELECT` clause, you can't have one column's computation rely upon a different column's value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
column1
,column2
,column3
,column4
,(column5 + reusethiscolumn) as Reusethiscolumn2
from
(
  select 
    column1
   ,column2
   ,column3
   ,column4
   ,column5
   ,case[computation here] as reusethiscolumn
  from table
) AS SubQ
```